# Google Cloud: Compute VM Instances; can't sudo anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sudo

I got a VM for a client on GC.  While trying to fix an issue to copy file by FTP, I added the 2 accounts I had, including the original one for the VM to the group www-data.

Since that, I cannot make any sudo. it's asking me for the root password. Which I do not previously created since it's usually not needed on Google VMs.

I get this message:

```
    xxxxxxx@wordpress-xxxxxxx-vm:/etc$ sudo su

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for xxxxx:
```

How can I get root access to fix that mess?

This message seems to mean that the users would be removed from sudoers?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I saw from another post that I may have done this:
Instead of typing the intended:

usermod -aG groupname username
I instead typed I believe it was the following:

usermod -G groupname username
What happened? Well it did add me to one group, but removed me from all the others including sudo.

Comment: I think new users are automatically added to `google-sudoers` group. Perhaps just add a new user to your project and ssh into the machine as that user? There might be smarter ways to do this...

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your help.  I saw some help around this but I seems to imply that we use IAM for the server access.  Meanwhile, I contnued to search and found a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is that the issue was caused by me forgetting to put -a when I made a usermod -aG groupname username. SO my google user was removed from many groups from /etc/group

/etc/sudoers was correct in fact.

To fix it I had play with mounting the drive on another VM to fix the file and then recreate a new VM with that fixed drive.